# Regex inside braces (curly brackets) -- gnu parallel / xargs / find

Tags: regex, bash, shell, parallel-processing, curly-braces

I'm having trouble with braces (curly brackets) using GNU parallel (http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

I have a list of four files:

```
file1.txt.super
file2.txt.super
file3.txt.super
file4.txt.super
```

If I issue: `ls * | parallel "mkdir ./{.}"`

I get returned four directories:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

My question is, how can I simply return four directories called:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

I have read http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919 but have been unable to implement these regex's with gnu parallel. I think I'm missing something here. Also, any examples with much more complicated regex would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have parallel installed, therefore can't test or read the docs. `parallel mkdir file{1..4}` would be my guess.

Comment: Thank-you to all who took the time to write/reply. There are certainly some excellent answers here and I'm sure these will all be very helpful to others learning `gnu parallel`. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it appears you are *missing something here*.  The [linuxjournal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919) article explains features of shell parameter expansion. Those braces (which are always preceded by `$`) are unrelated to `parallel` utility's default *replacement strings*, which coincidently use braces. The [parallel documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) shows command line options allow arbitrary strings to be used instead of its brace-enclosed defaults.

For example the *replacement string* `{.}` in your example could be changed to `%foo`

```
ls * | parallel --extensionreplace %foo "mkdir ./%foo"
```

More information about `${…}` from the linuxjournal article can be found in the `man bash` page, in the  **Parameter Expansion** section.

Since you asked in the comment on @AdamLiss answer, here is a *way to (ab)use the curly braces* and the `--colsep` parameter to perform your task:

```
ls * | parallel --colsep '\.' "mkdir ./{1}"
```

Note: this `--colsep` *trick* (like the `sed` proposed by @AdamLiss) will produce undesirable results if the filenames contain more than two periods (since the pathname is truncated at the first period.)

However, since the `--colsep` parameter is a *regular expression*, this should be resilient to periods elsewhere in the filename:

```
ls * | parallel --colsep '\.[^\.]*$' "mkdir ./{1.}"
```

Note: `--extensionreplace` isn't working due to a bug in the current (21120422) version of parallel.  But since `parallel` is an a perl script, you can fix it by changing:

```
    "extensionreplace|er" => \$::opt_U,
```

to

```
    "extensionreplace|er=s" => \$::opt_U,
```

Comment: +1 Absolutely brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for. Your use of `--colsep` regex is clear and very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: The answer today would be: `parallel --plus mkdir ./{..}`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using `sed`, here's a work-around:

```
ls * | sed 's/\..*//' | parallel "mkdir ./{}"
```

Comment: +1 this is an excellent use of `sed` and a perfect work-around. But is there a more succinct method? Is there a better way to (ab)use the curly braces?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
ls * | parallel echo {.} | parallel mkdir {.}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what the ".super" is or where it goes when you run parallel, or the use of "{.}" in the parallel command.  AFAIK, parallel works like xargs and only understands `{}`.   What am I missing?

In any case, I would achieve the goal with a for loop:

```
for f in *; do mkdir "${f%%.*}"; done
```

Or, if you really care about parallelism for jobs this short:

```
for f in *; do mkdir "${f%%.*}" & done
```

Comment: You're missing the documentation to `parallel`: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Comment: Hm.  I apparently have a different version on my system; no {.} mentioned in the local man page.  Thanks for doing my Googling for me, @AdamLiss.

Comment: +1 Nice use of a loop to make parallel. I'm getting the sneaking suspicion that gnu parallel only understands `{}` and `{.}`  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Per the doc @AdamLiss linked above, GNU parallel understands a variety of {}-related expressions, but as far as pathname-munging it looks like you can remove the leading directory and/or a single trailing extension, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [example in the manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__removing_two_file_extensions_when_processing_files_and_calling_gnu_parallel_from_itself), the following should work, even though it is not exactly beautiful:

```
ls *.txt.super| parallel --er {txt} 'echo {txt}|parallel "mkdir ./{.}"'
```

Removing the second file extension is done by calling parallel from parallel and aliasing the `{.}` string to `{txt}` in the parent instance of parallel.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do here, but I get returned: `/bin/bash: {txt}: command not found`

Comment: It does not work for me either (parallel does not seem to recognize the `--er` option and interprets the `{txt}` as command), but according to the latest manual page this is the way it should work. Might be a bug in parallel.

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger you are correct. `--er` not working is due to a bug in `parallel`.  See my answer for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the already great answers here, I'm pretty sure the simplest solution (probably what @Steve was looking for) is the following:

```
ls * | parallel --plus mkdir {..}
```

The `{.}` *replacement string* in [gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) is meant to "trim down" the string to the outermost `.` character. I believe you can trim down a string up to 3 `.` levels.

This means that `{.}` will trim down only one level to `file1.txt`, `{..}` will trim down two level to `file1`, and `{...}` will trim down third level.